# How gold funds can give different profit

Tags: india, mutual-funds, gold

I am looking at different gold bonds available in India, and came across some top performing funds from `etmoney` site.

I got a doubt on the profits generated by these funds. If they invest the money in gold then gold price will be same in a country, so how the profit will change in this case?

Also when I looked at the below image, it says `DSP world Gold Fund` is on top, but there is no rating for it or there is no rating on its consistency also. If it is a top fund then why it is not rated?

Here is a [comparison of some top funds](https://www.etmoney.com/mutual-funds/featured/digital-gold-mutual-funds/25) :

[image: Gold Funds comparison]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If they invest the money in gold then gold price will be same in a country, so how the profit will change in this case?

It will be different because,.

1. Expense ratio is different.
2. Purchase price variations
3. Amount kept as cash and pending investment
4. Redemption pressure
5. Corpus size